# How variable is a typical U.S. 110V outlet current?

Tags: current, outlet

How much does the power vary in a typical U.S. wall outlet over time?

Note: lightning spikes are an obvious event that seem like will surely cause a massive power spike, hence "surge" protectors.

Comment: Lightning surges don't really count as "variation" in power supply. Are you asking about variation in voltage, frequency, available current...?

Comment: I suppose I'm asking about current, which seems to be the metric electronic devices are rated for.  Was thinking that current or voltage can vary, which could cause problems.

Comment: Given that the current is dependent on the load, and the load could be anything from a nightlight to a dishwasher, you might say that there really isn't a "typical outlet current".

Comment: FYI, standard US mains voltage is **120** volts, not 110. If you look from 110, you'll see a lot more variation than there is.

Comment: This is going to be a very hard question to answer with any surety, as the NA grid is a collection of utilities and policies that try to allow for load and supply and all that. And each region will have its variations and exceptions. Everyone will have a story to tell about what the service is like in their area at some time, but little of that info will be generally representational. Equipment is designed to handle a wide variation in voltage, some all the way down to less than 100V. I've _heard_ that a +/-10% variation away from 120V nominal is a good minimum requirement, but who knows?

Comment: @JohnAllen: if you explain why you are asking the question we may be able to help better. Your question title gives us a big clue that you are not familiar with electrical terminology.

Answer (score 2):

The normal supply voltage at the meter is 120 volts +/-5% or 114 to 126 volts. Voltage drop between the meter to the outlet that is farthest from the meter could make the minimum voltage as low as 104 volts, but 110 volts would be more typical. Utilities in the USA usually maintain the normal voltage range quite reliably. There is data available showing typical magnitude, duration and frequency of short-term voltage surges, sags and outages.

The supply ratings for electrical and electronic devices are voltage and frequency. The current or power rating of a device is the maximum current or power that the device will take from the supply. The device determines how much current is drawn. The supply voltage can influence the current drawn, but the supply current available doesn't influence the current drawn.

Edit: By "device," I mean a product that is plugged into an outlet. Component part ratings are more complex.

Edit re outlet current ratings:

Household 120 volt circuits are rated to provide either 15 amps or 20 amps and supplied through 15 or 20 amp fuses or circuit breakers. Kitchen counter outlets and bathroom outlets are required to be supplied by 20 amp circuits. Other outlets can be connected to 15 amp circuits. Unless there is only one outlet on the circuit, any single plug-in item is not supposed to require more than 80% of the circuit rating or 12 amps for 15 amp circuits. Products that have 15 amp plugs are normally designed to take no more than 12 amps.

Comment: In addition, your electric panel (where the circuit breaker or fuses are located), will be rated as 60, 100, 150 or 200 amp service etc. depending on the incoming wire size (from 6 gauge for 60 amp service to 2/0 gauge for 200 amp service).  This determines the total current you can draw at once.